# Exclude last hour/data point from Kibana timeline vizualisation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to create a Kibana dashboard visualization simply showing the number (count) of events created over the set time.

This works fine, but when adjusting the time range, the line chart always drops off at the end, because the time span isn't finished, so is still gathering data. See this chart for an example:

[image: Event Chart]

How can I avoid this drop off at the end? Given that the Kibana preset time frames are relative like "Last 1 minute", "Last 1 Hour", "Last 7 Days" etc, I'm not sure it will be possible to essentially ditch the last datapoint?

As it gets closer to the X:59 of the hour, the data is correctly in line. But then at X:00 it acts like the count was zero, whereas really we're just right at the top of the hour.

The Y-axis is set to `Count` aggregation, and the X-axis bucket is Aggregation: `Date Histogram`, Field: `Created`, Interval: `Auto`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What if you preset the *interval* as **hourly** from the *aggregation bucket*? Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

You can *exclude* a particular value, only if you're using the **terms aggregation**, where you can specify a pattern to ignore that particular value from showing it in the graph.

This [section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_2) pretty much elaborates on using *patterns*. But what I'm not sure is that whether it would go along with a `datetime` or a `time` field. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting drop_last_bucket to one?  This will keep the last time period from displaying on your chart, because the time slice may still be collecting data.